# Dependent Drop Down select codeigniter Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Im trying to get houses to be filled on the second dropdown from their respective estates selected in the first drop down. Im getting no results in the second dropdown.

This is the HTML:

```
                           <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group drop-custum">
                                    <select id="estate" name="estate" data-live-search="true" class="form-control show-tick"
                                    onchange="get_houses(this.value)">
                                        <option value="">-- Estate --</option>
                                        <?php
                                        $sql = $this->db->query("select * from estates ORDER BY estate_name asc");
                                        $result = $sql->result();
                                        foreach ($result as $estates):
                                            ?>
                                            <option class="text-uppercase"
                                                    value="<?= $estates->estate_name?>"> <?= $estates->estate_name?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group drop-custum">

                                    <select name="house" data-live-search="true" id="house"
                                            class="form-control show-tick">
                                        <option value="">-- House --</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

This is the AJAX:

```
 function get_houses()
 {
$.ajax({
    url:"fill_houses/",
    type:"POST",
    data:'estate_name='+val,
    success:function(data)
    {
        $("#house").html(data);
        alert('success');
    }
});

}
```

This is the  PHP:

```
public function fill_houses()
{

    $query = "select * from houses where estate_name='" . $_POST["estate_name"] . "' order by house_number asc ";
    $result = $query->result();
    foreach ($result as $estates):
        '<option class="text-uppercase" value="'.$estates->house_id.'"> '.$estates->house_number.'</option>';
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Because you forgot `echo` in `fill_houses`?

Comment: `$query` is a string, you can't call a `result` method on it.

Comment: And `get_houses` in js knows nothing about `val` variable.

Comment: done the `echo` @u_mulder...still nothing

Comment: @PeterMader could you kindly post with corrections, i'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return the value back in php function `fill_houses()`.

```
public function fill_houses()
{

    $query = $this->db->query("select * from houses where estate_name='" . $_POST["estate_name"] . "' order by house_number asc ");
    $result = $query->result();
    foreach ($result as $estates):
      return  '<option class="text-uppercase" value="'.$estates->house_id.'"> '.$estates->house_number.'</option>';
    endforeach;
}
```

also in javascript ajax function `get_houses()` you need to get the variable. and a couple of edit.

```
function get_houses(val)
 {
$.ajax({
    url:"fill_houses/",
    type:"POST",
    data: { 'estate_name': val} ,
    success:function(data)
    {
        $("#house").html(data);
        alert('success');
    }
});

}
```

Comment: You are Welcome @Lexie

Comment: heyy, me again, why is it not posting to the `<select name="house" data-live-search="true" id="house"
                                                class="form-control show-tick">
                                            
                                        </select>`